# Nonlinear second-order ODE $yy'' - (y')^{2} = y^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE to solve.
$$
yy'' - (y')^{2} = y^4
$$
I tried to substitute $y'$ by $v$, and then I get the following:

$$
yv' - v^{2} = y^4.
$$

I can't go further. I can't see what I'm supposed to do in order to solve it.

I saw a solution involving Bessel function. But, is it possible to transform the first ODE into an exact, linear, or Bernoulli equation?

Any hint, please. Thanks.

Comment: If it was $y\cdot y'' + (y')^2 = (y\cdot y')'$ this would be a little easier I think. Not sure if that relationship is useful here

Comment: Compute the derivative of $y'/y$ to simplify. However, this is not the full distance...

Comment: Hint:
$$\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)' = \frac{y''}{y} - \frac{y'^2}{y^2} = y^2
\implies \frac{y'}{y}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)' - yy' = 0
\implies \left(\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^2 - y^2\right)' = 0$$ BTW, the answer doesn't involve any Bessel function.

Comment: @achillehui: Your comment/hint surpasses the threshold of an answer.

Comment: The ad-hoc strategy for solving an ODE looking like this is to (a) look for a form like $d/dx[f(y,y')]$ or the second derivative in the ODE or (b) multiply by $y'$ or $y''$ and try (a).

Comment: @achillehui, thanks so much, man!
I got it now!

Comment: How about answering your own question so us curious onlookers can see the full solution?  Cheers!

Comment: @achillehui I concur with LutzL. You should make this an answer, if not just to have the question not be bumped by Community in a few months unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is using $v = y' = \frac{dy}{dt}$ but expressing the equation a different way
$$y'' = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dv}{dy} = v\frac{dv}{dy} $$
Thus
$$ yv\frac{dv}{dy} = v^2 + y^4 $$

From here, let $zy = v^2$ so $$z + y\frac{dz}{dy} = 2v\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{2}{y} \left( zy + y^4 \right) = 2z + 2y^3$$

$$\frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{z}{y} + 2y^2$$

This a linear first-order ODE that you can solve

Answer (score 0):

If we set $y(t)=\exp\left(f(t)\right)$ then we have $f(t)=\log y(t)$ and:
$$ f''(t) = \frac{y y''-(y')^2}{y^2}\tag{1}$$
hence the original ODE is mapped to:
$$ f''(t) = \exp(2 f(t)) \tag{2}$$
and by multiplying both sides by $2f'$ then integrating we get:
$$ \left(f'(t)\right)^2 = e^{2\, f(t)} + C\tag{3} $$
that is a separable ODE. To solve it, we just need to find a primitive for $\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}+C}}$.

Assuming $C=0$ that task is pretty easy to accomplish. If $C\neq 0$, a dilogarithm is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by $(1+ y^{'2})= \sec^2 \phi, $

and let $ \cos^2 \phi = U ;$

It reduces to the form:

$$ \dfrac{d(log\; U)}   {d\,( log\, y^2 )  } = (y^4 U^2 - U+1) $$

We can proceed with it further.